# Any other way to calculate range of transformed variable?

Tags: data-transformation, random-variable, range

I have been doing questions related to transformations of 2d random variables.

In a question I have to find a range for 
$$u = (x-y)/2
$$
and
$$v = y 
$$
where $x,y > 0$

So is it necessary that I plot a graph for $2u+v>0$ and $v>0$ to find the range for pdf or is there any other way?

Comment: Once you get familiar with the topic, you may become confident that you can write and solve equations that determine the support of a bivariate distribution. But as you begin, trying to plot a graph may be easier to understand. // In my Answer I use simulation to provide an intuitive view of the support.

Answer (score 2):

**Support of a Bivariate Distribution.**
As @whuber points out this is a mathematical problem just about the boundaries of a region after transformation. I anticipate that
the next step for you may be to use such transformations for
probability distributions, which you mention in your question. I hope you will look at the boundaries in this answer for now---and for later, take a look at the probability distributions.

**Looking at two univariate distributions.** Let's look at a particular example, using simulation in R.
Then I hope a general solution will make more sense. We begin by looking
at the two univariate distributions, for $U$ and $V,$ separately.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independently distributed as $\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda = 1/\mu = 0.1).$
Then $E(X) = E(Y) = 10,$ so $E(X-Y) = E(X) - E(Y) = 0,$ and 
$E(U) = E\left(\frac{X-Y}{2}\right) = 0.$

Also, $Var(X) = Var(Y) = 10^2,$ so $Var(X-Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) = 200,$ and
$Var(U)  = \frac 1 4 (200) = 50.$

Random variables $X$ and $Y$ both have support $(, \infty).$ The support of the random variable $U$ is $(-\infty, \infty).$ For example, if $X$ is huge and $Y$ is near $0,$ and $U$ could be huge. Also, extremely negative values
of $U$ are easy to imagine. The support of random variable $V$ is $(0, \infty),$ the same as for $Y.$

Now for a simulation. With only $10\,000$ sampled values from each distribution we can
only expect to approximate means and standard deviations to about 1 or 2 significant digits, but that is good enough to see our theoretical computations above aren't terribly wrong.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rexp(10000, .1);  y = rexp(10000, .1)
u = (x-y)/2;  v = y
mean(u);  sd(u)
[1] 0.1129585    # aprx E(U) = 0
[1] 7.034309     # aprx SD(U) = sqrt(50) =  7.0711
mean(v);  sd(v)
[1] 9.919974     # aprx E(V) = 10
[1] 9.968185     # aprx SD(V) = sqrt(100) = 10
```

The shape of the distribution of $U$ is suggested by a histogram of
our simulated sample of size $10\,000. This is a [Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Related_distributions) distribution.

```
hist(u, br=40, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

**Looking at their joint distribution.** However, for the full story about your transformation, we need to investigate
the *joint* distribution of $(U,V).$ We can get an intuitive view of it
by looking at a scatterplot of our simulated values. Perhaps you were surprised
that the left boundary of the support of the *bivariate* distribution is
given by a diagonal line. Maybe you can try some values of $x$ and $y$ to determine
why some points are 'missing' from the support. For example why is $u =-20, v = 20$
impossible?

[image]

*Notes:* (1) Better estimates of means and standard deviations of $U$ and $V$ could
have been attained by using more than $10\,000$ values of each. But with more
points the scatterplot becomes more difficult to interpret. So $10\,000$ is a compromise.

(2) From the scatterplot it is clear that $U$ and $V$ are *not* independent. For example,
$P(-21 < U < -19) > 0$ and $P(19 < V < 21) > 0,$ but $P(-21 < U < -19,\,19 < V < 21) = 0.$

*Addendum:* Implementing suggestion by @whuber just for boundary, no distribution (color added); see Comment:

```
x = c(rep(0,50),1:50, 0, 10)
y = c(1:50, rep(0,50),0, 10)
u = (x-y)/2; v=y
frb=hsv((0:102)/102, 1, .7)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 plot(x,y, pch=20, col=frb)
 plot(u,v, pch=20, col=frb)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: For this problem, which is a purely mathematical one that is unrelated to random variables (it's solely about the transformation), simulation makes little sense and is inefficient.  Instead, one exploratory method is to generate some systematic array of points in the domain of the transformation *and especially along its boundary*, apply the transformation to each of those points, and plot their images.  Obviously those images will all lie within the image of the transformation; and the images of the boundary points will usually sketch out all or part of the boundary of the image.

Comment: @whuber: Yes, In different situations, I have transformed grid patterns with good effect. Very efficient for some transformations. The difficulty here is that the only two boundaries for x and y are the positive x and y axes. And transforming a square grid gives a trapezoid with misleading right and upper boundaries. // Also, it is reasonable to anticipate that the very next step for this student might be to transform actual random variables, so I wanted to look ahead to that.

Comment: In this case, transforming the boundaries will show the boundary of the image.  Transforming one more point in the interior of the domain will show on which side of the boundaries the image must lie.  But I do appreciate your anticipation of working with random variables.